# Why do i paint on the wrong side of my object?

Tags: texture-painting

i am trying to paint my cat. However when i try to paint where the cursor is in the first picture the colour ends up on the neck. It does this where ever i paint regardless witch way i´m facing. How do i fix this?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What does your active UV map look like?

Comment: I added a picture :) i have no idea why it looks like that

Comment: Your normals are inverted, meaning when you paint the front of the head, you are hitting the neck with your spray can. In edit mode, select everything, and go shift N or Mesh > Normals > Recalculate outside

Comment: Thank you! it worked :)

Comment: Hi Clara.. this seems to have been cleared up OK, and it's a duplicate, so it's fair to 'close the case'